# How to get top 5 documents based on a stored field value in elasticsearch?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, filter, elasticsearch-aggregation

Example - test scores of one subject of students are stored in Elastic search index. Now I want to find top 5 students who scored highest in that subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me show it by using the example, But the first understand the concept.

First query based on the given subject, in my example famous `math` subject :) and then it will fetch all the students, having `math` subject, after that `sort` in `desc` order based in their `score` and then `size` param restricted the result to top `k` students.

Imp links related to answer:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-from-size.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html

### Create an index

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "sid": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "subject" :{
                "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "score" :{
                "type" : "integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index some docs

```
{
   "sid" : 1,
   "subject" :"math",
   "score" : 50
}

{
   "sid" : 2,
   "subject" :"math",
   "score" : 60
}
{
   "sid" : 3,
   "subject" :"math",
   "score" : 70
}
{
   "sid" : 4,
   "subject" :"math",
   "score" : 90
}
{
   "sid" : 5,
   "subject" :"math",
   "score" : 99
}

{
   "sid" : 6,
   "subject" :"math",
   "score" : 100
}
```

Search query to search on `subject` and sort results based on marks and return top 3 students.

```
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "score": {
                "order": "desc" --> define sort order
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "subject": "math"
        }
    },
    "size":3 -->important, you can change it to fetch top K students, Just change 3 to whatever no you want to fetch.
}
```

### Search query result

```
{
            "_index": "leaderboard",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "5",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "sid": 6,
               "subject": "math",
               "score": 100
            },
            "sort": [
               100
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "leaderboard",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "sid": 4,
               "subject": "math",
               "score": 90
            },
            "sort": [
               90
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "leaderboard",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "sid": 3,
               "subject": "math",
               "score": 70
            },
            "sort": [
               70
            ]
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply sort searched results by the field you want i.e `score`
This doc may help you https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html